# showing blank screen every time while i tried to post on facebook after user has logged in

Tags: iphone, facebook, uiwebview

Iam using FaceBook Connect api to connect to Facebook in my app.Iam posting message on my wall using this api.but after user has logged in when i tried to post next time,blank white screen is presented for few seconds and then disappeared,after that post screen is presented.It is happening every time when I am posting message on Fb

I need to remove blank screen.